# The total number of elements in the shopping cart is not refreshed even though there's a singleton class managing the cart state

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

My site has a header that displays the total number of items in the shopping cart. To do so, I've created a file named shoppingCart.js as follows:

```
export default new class ShoppingCart {
  constructor() {
    this.loadCart();
  }

  saveCart() {
    window.localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(this.cache));
  }

  loadCart() {
    const cart = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('cart') || null);
    this.cache = (cart && isArray(cart) && cart.length) ? cart : [];
  }

  removeProduct(product) {
    //Remove the product from the this.cache array.
    //Save the cart in the localStorage
  }

  addProduct(product) {
    //Update this.cache, first...
    //Save the cart in the localStorage
  }

  get products() {
    return Object.freeze([...this.cache]);
  }
}();
```

Then, in the HeaderView.vue, I imported the above class and created a computed method to 
get the total number of items in the cart:

```
import ShoppingCart from '../helpers/shoppingCart';

export default {
  name: 'HeaderView',

  computed: {
    totalCartItems() {
      return ShoppingCart.products.length;
    },
  },
};
```

On the ProductView.vue page (where the product is added to the cart), I also import the ShoppingCart (as above) and have a method named "addToCart" that is supposed to add a given product to the cart:

```
methods: {
  addToCart() {
    ShoppingCart.addProduct(
      this.product
    );
  },
},
```

However, no matter what I do, or tried, the total number of items in the cart is not displayed in the header, unless I reload the page. (I'd like it to be refreshed once the "addToCart" method of ProductView.vue gets called.

Would you please let me know what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Note that I need to use modules to handle this and I don't want to use the "Vue.prototype.$" or VueJS Plugins to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shopping cart object is not reactive by default. you could try adding it to the reactivity watch by putting it into the data object/function (untested)

```js
import ShoppingCart from '../helpers/shoppingCart';

export default {
  name: 'HeaderView',

  data: function() {
    return {
      shoppingCart: ShoppingCart
    };
  }

  computed: {
    totalCartItems() {
      return this.shoppingCart.products.length;
    },
  },
};
```

Alternatively, I would suggest that you use Vuex. Seems like the functionality you're trying to create is solved with vuex.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, this fixed the problem. I'll switch to Vuex, eventually, but for now, I was trying to learn a few things here. :) Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misusing computed values.
From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods):

> computed properties are cached based on their dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed.

That means, the computed value cache will be refreshed only if a attribute (used by the computed value) is updated. Here, you do not use an attribute (you do not access `this.` in `totalCartItems` ) so the computed value is never refreshed.

As specified in the documentation, can you use a method instead of a computed value?